# Set maximum width and css color for the specific (not all) popover container (help icon1)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, bootstrap-popover

I am wondering how to apply CSS selectors to a specific container.

I tried to apply the following CSS change to the help icon1 and not help icon2.

The CSS change that I would like to apply to helpicon1 popover are:- 
h6 red color and Set max width of Popover Container to 385px

http://jsfiddle.net/E5Ly5/683/

```js
$('.ico').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $(this).next('.popper-content').html();
    }
});

$('.icon2').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $(this).next('.popper-content').html();
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}
.popover-title {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.popover-content{
  max-width:385px;
}
  div.test div.hide h6{
    color: red;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="test"> 
               <i class="fa fa-question-circle ico" 
               data-toggle="popover"  data-placement="right" 
               data-trigger="hover" >help icon1</i>
               
<div class="popper-content hide"><h6>
Red color Title. </h6>
  <ul>
    <li>Popover container apply max -width: 385px</li>
    <li> test1.</li>
  </ul>
</div></div>      

<div class="test"> 
               <i class="fa fa-question-circle icon2" 
               data-toggle="popover"  data-placement="right" 
               data-trigger="hover" >help icon2</i>
               
<div class="popper-content hide"><h6>
Black color title </h6>
  <ul>
    <li>Popover Container no specific width.</li>
    <li>Test2.</li> </ul>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Just a little tip: In Mozilla Firefox, when you open the inspector (Windows: Ctrl+Shift+i, OS X Cmd+Alt+i), over the inspector tab, find or select the element and right click over it and click over Copy > CSS Selector.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I can only copy element instead of copy css selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do cannot be done with the way you are loading the content. The bootstrap popover element renders the popper-content in a different part of the DOM that cannot be targeted.

Why not simply attach a class that contains `color:red` directly on the `h6` you want?

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/E5Ly5/684/

Comment: Thank you but Is there a way to set maximum width for the popover container when user hover over the helpIcon1 only?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to target a parent container with css. Since the popper-content lies INSIDE the popover container and is produced dynamically it cannot be done. I would add a class to all popover elements for 385px and would add a container in all OTHER popovers that I want smaller - if this container is smaller than 385px then it would render at the container width as a maximum.

Comment: I tried set the width but it looks weird on the text. http://jsfiddle.net/E5Ly5/688/